# OpenMP does not terminates

Tags: c, openmp

I've took an [example](https://curc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming/OpenMP-C.html) of the simple OpenMP code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int i;
    int thread_id;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

        for( int i = 0; i < omp_get_num_threads(); i++){
            if(i == omp_get_thread_num()){
                printf("Hello from process: %d\n", thread_id);
            }
            #pragma omp barrier
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled it with `gcc -fopenmp omp_test_hello.c -o a.exe`.
I did not change or set any environment variables (I've decided that internal directives in code should work similarly). When I execute file I get the following output:

```
Hello from process: 0
Hello from process: 3
Hello from process: 3
Hello from process: 3
```

After that, the execution of the program does not stop, so it seems that something blocks it from termination.

I've tried even more simple example of the code without the barrier and for loop. It does not terminates similarly, though the output include "signals" from all threads:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int i;
    int thread_id;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Hello from process: %d\n", thread_id);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello from process: 2
Hello from process: 1
Hello from process: 0
Hello from process: 3
```

I've managed to test these examples also on Linux and get same results.
So what could be the problem?

Comment: FYI, I just ran your code (1st code example)  on Windows, without changing anything and it worked fine and exited normally.   I am using `gcc.exe -Wall -g -std=c17 -fopenmp -I<compiler path> -c ,<main.c path> -o obj\Debug\main.o`  My only suggestion is that you have an unused variable `i`, and I would remove `omp_get_num_threads()` from within the `for` loop.  i.e. use `int num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();`, then `for( int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++){...`.  So I have to ask, what exactly do you mean when you say _"execution of the program does not stop"_?

Comment: ... Could it be that your IDE has settings that force you to hit the return key in the console after a run ?  (eg maybe to execute a hidden getchar() like function to allow you to see the results without running in debug.)  When I use the Code::Blocks IDE for example, it has a  _"pause when execution ends"_ option under its target options.

Comment: There is a data race in your code (`thread_id`), so do not expect correct output of thread ids. Otherwise your code is ok, it should finish normally. Use `int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because problem is not reproducible with code example or settings information shown.  OP is able to observe the expected output, so the code compiles and runs.  This is possibly caused by an IDE setting to _pause when execution ends_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by reinstalling mingw compiler.